# Intento lanzar un fragment desde mi recyclerAdapter en otro fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment, adapter

Es decir, tengo este metodo en mi FragmentHome.jav y funciona, lo cual me lleva a mi siguiente Fragment_StoreCat.java junto con los atributos de mi item seleccionado:

```
RecyclerView showstore; //etc, etc, etc.....


showstore.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(),
                showstore,
                new RecyclerTouchListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                Fragment fm = new Fragment_StoreCat();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("store_id", list.get(position).getUser_id());
                args.putString("store_image",list.get(position).getUser_image());
                args.putString("banner_image",list.get(position).getUser_main_banner());
                storeeditor.putString("store_id",list.get(position).getUser_id());

                storeeditor.apply();
                fm.setArguments(args);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container, fm,"Frgament_StoreCat")
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));
```

Lo que intento es lanzar este mismo metodo desde mi HomeAdapter.java que va asi:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HomeAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

final int pos = position;
Home_Model mList = modelList.get(pos);


Glide.with(context)
        .load(Baseurl.IMG_PROFILE_URL + mList.getUser_image())
        .placeholder(R.drawable.icon)
        .transition(withCrossFade())
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .dontAnimate()
        .into(holder.image);
holder.title.setText(mList.getUser_fullname());

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
```

//Aqui es donde ya intente con intent pero no secomo pasar a mi Fragment_StoreCat.java

```
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

En realidad las Activity se inician con Intent y los Fragment se cargan mediante una Transacción, lo cual ya estas realizando.

Si estas es `HomeAdapter.java` esta clase debe cargar un layout que contenga un contenedor (por ejemplo `main_container` ) donde se realizara la transacción de fragmentos.

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    
     //Aqui es donde ya intente con intent pero no se como pasar a mi Fragment_StoreCat.java

                Fragment fm = new Fragment_StoreCat();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container, fm,"Frgament_StoreCat")
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();



    }
});
```